# Grails find Domain and then Save it

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

What I want to do is find a domain and then either create a new one or save the pre-existing one.  Here is the code that I am currently working with (in this project, skeleton is the package name):

```
    def save() {
        Class lob = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('skeleton.'+params.lob.name)
        def instance = lob.get(params.lob.id)
        if (instance){
            params.data.each { name, value ->
                if (instance.metaClass.hasProperty(name)){
                    instance[name] = value
                }
            }
        }else{
            instance = new lob()
            params.data.each { name, value ->
                if (instance.metaClass.hasProperty(name)){
                    instance[name] = value
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  Can anyone help me with the solution?

Comment: ataylor has the reason below why your code is failing, but you should also look at the `findOrCreateBy` GORM method, which would let you DRY your code up quite a bit.  It either returns an existing object or instantiates a new, unsaved one that you can fill in the values on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object returned by `getDomainClass` is an instance of [`GrailsDomainClass`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClass.html).  To get the actual domain class on which you can call `get`, first call `getClazz` on it.  For example:

```
Class lob = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('skeleton.'+params.lob.name).clazz
```

In addition, you'll have to call `newInstance` on the class object rather than using the `new` keyword to create a new instance.

Comment: Why do you need to call `newInstance()` instead of using `new`?

Comment: The `new` keyword needs a the name of a type but in this case it's a `Class` object.